# Generic way of retrieving an object out of the database

Tags: c#, generics

I am trying to make a part of my code generic.

The ungeneric code:

```
public static User GetUser(int id)
  {
     using (var db = new BroodNodigContext())
     {
        return db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == id);
     }
  }
```

The code which I need but chopped to it's brim:

```
public static object FooBar<T>(int id)
  {
     using (var db = new DatabaseContext())
     {
        return db.T.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Id == Id);
     }
  }
```

What I got:

```
public static object GetTypeOutOfDatabase<T>(int id)
  {
     using (var db = new DatabaseContext())
     {
        dynamic test = typeof(T);
        db.Set<test>();

        return null;
     }
  }
```

I was told That I could use `db.Set<>()` to make it generic, but I fail to use correctly. 
Do you perhaps know how to make the `T` into a reference type (like `User`) so I can put it in the `db.set<>()`?

Comment: It's just `db.Set<T>()` that you need, forget about the `test` variable and also return a `T`, not an object.

Comment: Making everything in the codebase an `object` seems like an invitation for a variety of other potential problems.

Answer (score 0):

Entity framework provides a Find function which will look things up by primary Key.

**NOTE** this takes in an object[] which is used in the find method, just pass your id in an let EF work it's magic, as a hack I've provided params to make it easier to call

```
public static object FooBar<T>(params object[] id)
{
    using (var db = new DatabaseContext())
    {
        return db.Set<T>().Find(Id);
    }
}
```

This will work for your use case but later on you may find you need to generate your own custom expression which will be a bit more complicated